# Neglecting the records from SQL Query

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, filtering

I have two date columns; `given_schedule` and `delivery_schedule`. To query them, I use the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table2 
WHERE CONVERT(date, given_schedule) >= CONVERT(date, DATEADD(dd, -3, GETDATE()))
```

This `SELECT` returns all the rows within the last 3 days. What I need to do, though, is remove all of the returned rows which have today's date in the `delivery_schedule`.

How should I update my query to do this? Essentially, I want to remove anything returned by the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM table2 
WHERE CONVERT(date, delivery_schedule) = CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
```

Comment: What does this have to do with `C#`?

Comment: i am working in windows form with sqlconection thats why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table2
 WHERE CONVERT(date, given_schedule) >=CONVERT(date, DATEADD(dd, -3, GETDATE()))
 AND CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) <> CONVERT(date, delivery_schedule)
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
SELECT * 
FROM table2  
WHERE CONVERT(date, given_schedule) != GETDATE() 
AND CONVERT(date, given_schedule)>=CONVERT(date, DATEADD(dd, -3, GETDATE()))
```

It's not clear what this question has to do with C# though, since this is SQL code